# Refining code: Is there a better way to map one (shorter) array to another (longer) array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have a React project that uses an array of colors for styling a few things:

```
export const backlightArray = [
    theme.capri,
    theme.aqua,
    theme.oceanGreen,
    theme.yellow,
    'orange',
    theme.lightRed
];
```

and another array of objects with attributes for anchor tags:

```
const siteStart = [
    { label: 'StackOverflow', href: 'https://stackoverflow.com' },
    { label: 'rwieruch', href: 'https://www.robinwieruch.de/blog' },
    { label: 'ITNext.io', href: 'https://itnext.io/' },
    { label: 'Dev.to', href: 'https://dev.to/' },
    {
        label: `ycombninator ('Hacker News')`,
        href: 'https://news.ycombinator.com/'
    },
    { label: 'OpenBase.io', href: 'https://openbase.io/' },
    { label: 'Coolors.co', href: 'https://coolors.co/' },
    { label: 'GitHub', href: 'https://www.github.com/' },
    { label: '/r/homelab/', href: 'https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/' },
];
```

(I've shortened this for the example, but right now this array has 14 links).

The colors array is shorter than the array of site objects.  I want the colors to repeat once they colors array ends, so I came up with this loop to add colors from the `backlightArray` for the length of the `siteStart` array:

```
let siteListColorsArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < siteStart.length; i++) {
    if (siteListColorsArray.length < siteStart.length) {
        backlightArray.map(color => siteListColorsArray.push(color));
    }
}
```

and then map those colors along with other shared attributes for the links like so:

```
const sites = siteStart.map((site, idx) => {
    site.target = '_blank';
    site.rel = 'noopener noreferrer';
    site.id = `${site.label.slice(0, 3)}-${idx}`; // this is for 'key'
    site.color = siteListColorsArray[idx];
    return site;
});

export default sites;
```

I wrote it this way so I could add /remove `label` and `href` objects to/from the `siteStart` array and not have to mess with any other attributes in the finished objects.

It works properly, but I am just wondering: does this code look decent to other people?  If you were to do something similar, what would you do differently?

Comment: The code seems clear to me and I understood every part of it :) as I am a newbie. may b there are more experienced developers who can say something about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a great answer that replaced this nested loop to create a longer array of colors:

```
let siteListColorsArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < siteStart.length; i++) {
    if (siteListColorsArray.length < siteStart.length) {
 /* lengths: (0)                           (13)            */
        backlightArray.map(color => siteListColorsArray.push(color));
 /*      (length = 6)                (iterates until > 13)         */
    }
}
```

with this ternary expression to subtract 1 from the modulus of `index % backlightArray.length` once the index is greater than 5 `(backlightArray.length -1)`:

```
let colorsLastIndex = backlightArray.length - 1;

const sites = siteStart.map((site, idx) => {
    site.id = `${site.label.slice(0, 3)}-${idx}`;
    const newIndex = idx > colorsLastIndex ? (idx % colorsLastIndex) - 1 : idx;
    site.color = backlightArray[newIndex];
    return site;
});
```

however, this solution made the `newIndex` return -1, resulting in a missing color value for that iteration.  When I `console.log(newIndex)`, you can see that the number goes below 0 and does not return to 5 - I wrote out the steps to illustrate (I performed the calculations in the console to verify):

```
/* start first iteration w/ index */
0
1
2
3
4
5
/* start newIndex = idx > colorsLastIndex ? (idx % colorsLastIndex) - 1
                    (6)       (6)            (6)      (5)          (- 1)  */
0  // 6 % 5 - 1  
1  // 7 % 5 - 1 
2  // 8 % 5 - 1 
3  // 9 % 5 - 1 
-1 // 10 % 5 - 1 
0  // 11 % 5 - 1 
1  // 12 % 5 - 1 
2  // 13 % 5 - 1
```

Here's the solution that worked for me  (note: `backlightArray.length` = 6):

```
const newIndex = idx >= backlightArray.length ? idx % backlightArray.length : idx;
    site.color = backlightArray[newIndex];

console.log(newIndex): 
/* start first iteration w/ idx */
0
1
2
3
4
5
/* start newIndex = (idx) >= backlightArray.length ? idx % backlightArray.length 
                     (6)           (6)               (6)  %  (6) */
0  // 6 % 6
1  // 7 % 6
2  // 8 % 6
3  // 9 % 6
4  // 10 % 6
5  // 11 % 6
0  // 12 % 6
1  // 13 % 6
```

Once the index gets to 6, which is 1 above 5 (the last color in `backlightArray`), 6 = `backlightArray.length`, and the condition becomes true.  Then, the remainder of index divided by 6 equals 0, and increases by one thereafter until the index reaches another factor of 6 (e.g. 12), at which point it becomes 0 again.  This condition also works:

```
newIndex = idx + 1 > backlightArray.length ? idx % backlightArray.length : idx;
```

`idx + 1` might be a little more illustrative of the logic.

This is a great pattern that reduces the need for unwieldy-looking nested loops.  Thanks so much for sharing!

Comment: looks good, I just did the logic in my head, I have not actually tried it so I missed that I dont have to actually substract one.

Comment: Yep - just use the original array length, too (don't subtract one from that, either).  You were making it too complicated ;)  Thanks for the pointers!  Couldn't have done it without you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the job for you:

```
colorsLastIndex = backlightArray.length - 1;

const sites = siteStart.map((site, idx) => {
  const newIndex = idx > colorsLastIndex ? (idx % colorsLastIndex) - 1 : idx;
  site.id = `${site.label.slice(0, 3)}-${idx}`; // this is for 'key'
  site.color = backlightArray[newIndex];
  return site;
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the response! I tried it out and it didn't quite work, but it definitely put me on the right track.  I'm going to answer w/ what I came up with.

Comment: alright might have missed something. But something similar should work.

Comment: It sure did!  I vaguely remember that pattern from a tutorial I watched, but I had to do some trial and error since it wasn't particularly obvious to me at the start.